# Why should foo-config.cmake and foo-config-version.cmake be separate?

Tags: cmake, packaging, buildconfiguration, software-packaging

In talks by Daniel Pfeiffer ([Effective CMake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk)) and by Deniz Bahadir ([More Modern CMake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7ndUhdQuU8)), and even in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html), it is suggested that (at least) to `.cmake` files be generated for using a repository with CMake in other projects: `foo-config.cmake` and `foo-config-version.cmake` (for package `foo`; another possible naming scheme is `FooConfig.cmake` and `FooConfigVersion.cmake`).

This already seems strange to me. Why shouldn't `foo-config.cmake` also have information/commands regarding the installed version? Is there some objective reason for the two separate files to exist, or is it just a CMake design 'gaffe'?

<sub>**Edit:** snipped the rest of this question, for focus and since I got something wrong.</sub>

Comment: "Why shouldn't foo-config.cmake also have information/commands regarding the installed version?" -- I assume this is a question about CMake's design (which I have answered) since it _is not an option_ to include this information meaningfully in `foo-config.cmake`.

Comment: @AlexReinking: Yes, sort of, see edit.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I don't think your edit changes my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why shouldn't foo-config.cmake also have information/commands regarding the installed version?

The package script `foo-config.cmake` is free to create targets (which cannot be deleted), set variables in the parent scope, and so on. Splitting `foo-config-version.cmake` into a script that runs in an isolated scope makes it easy for the package search to proceed without fear of clobbering variables. It would have been *possible* to incorporate all this functionality in one file (the way find *modules* do) but history has shown this practice to be error-prone and redundant.

Basically, there are two advantages:

1. **Isolation.** Running a version script won't clobber variables in the `find_package` caller. Once `foo-config.cmake` runs, it may set package variables, create targets, and so on with full confidence that the user intended this action.
2. **Reduced boilerplate.** The `CMakePackageConfigHelpers` can generate good version scripts at the cost of two lines in your `CMakeLists.txt` file. Given the new version range features in CMake 3.19, this is a welcome task to automate.

Comment: Isolation: That depends on what the package author put in each cmake file; it's not as though they're included in a different "mode", right? Well, in that case, it would have been possible to have the `foo-config.cmake` to be invokable with a boolean variable for whether you want just the meta-data about the package (including version etc.) or whether you want to go ahead and configure it.

Comment: @einpoklum - The `foo-config-version.cmake` files execute in their own scope. That's in the documentation [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#version-selection). The `foo-config.cmake` files execute in the scope of the `find_package` caller. It's akin to `include()` versus `add_subdirectory()`.

Comment: Reduced boilerplate: That's upside-down. Both the contents of `foo-config.cmake` and `foo-config-version.cmake` should be, in general, generated by CMake when you issue an appropriate install command. In other words - whether it's 2 files or 1, the user shouldn't have to handle the boilerplate anyway.

Comment: Well, you could have the `foo-config.cmake` execute in its own scope, and be made aware of that,  when it serves as today's `foo-config-version.cmake`, and execute in the caller scope otherwise. But, ok, I suppose it's not a frivolous distinction between the files. Also, I would name the two scripts differently to indicate that they're not "version" and "everything else", but rather "identifier" and "configurator" or something along those lines.

Comment: "Well, you could have the foo-config.cmake execute in its own scope, and be made aware of that" -- sort of, but in that case the package would have to set variables in the parent scope like `set(Foo_VERSION 1.0.0 PARENT_SCOPE)`, which would make migration from Find modules harder and generally be sad to look at. It's a trade-off.

Comment: "Reduced boilerplate: That's upside-down." -- it's reduced relative to CMake _not_ generating it. Generally the `foo-config.cmake` file is not auto-generated, but is configured (as in `configure_file`) and has calls to `find_dependency`, includes the `install(EXPORT)`-generated scripts, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234396/discussion-between-einpoklum-and-alex-reinking).

Answer (score 0):

To much for a comment but not a full answer:

A typical sequence in the projects I generate is using the [CMakePackageConfigHelper](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html) and [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html?highlight=gnuinstalldirs) modules
from CMake.

There is no need to generate a `foo-config-version.cmake` template. Just use the `write_basic_package_version_file` command from this module to get things done.

The `export` command comes handy if you want to use the config packages from the build directory without the need to install them.

See example:

```
# Support find_package(Foo NO_MODULE).
set(FOO_DOC_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR})
set(FOO_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
set(FOO_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(FOODIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

configure_package_config_file(foo-config.cmake.in "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo-config.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${FOO_CONFIG_PACKAGE_LOCATION}
  PATH_VARS FOODIR FOO_INCLUDE_DIR FOO_LIB_DIR FOO_DOC_DIR
)

write_basic_package_version_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo-config-version.cmake"
  VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)

# To make the component usable not only from the install directory but also from the build directory
export(
  TARGETS Foo
  FILE foo-export.cmake
)

install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo-config.cmake" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo-config-version.cmake"
  DESTINATION ${FOO_CONFIG_PACKAGE_LOCATION}
  COMPONENT development
)

install(EXPORT Foo
  DESTINATION ${FOO_CONFIG_PACKAGE_LOCATION}
  NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
  FILE foo-export.cmake
  COMPONENT development
)
```

Comment: Since this is a half-comment-half-answer - would you mind if edited my question, invalidating it, reflecting the fact that I don't need a  template for the version file?

Comment: Maybe my wording was bad. `foo-config-version.cmake` is a file in the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` generated by `write_basic_package_version_file` not a template. The default contents does not contain any information that can be found in the default `foo-config.cmake`.

Comment: You're right, it's not based on a template, it's the `-config.cmake` file that's based on a template in the CMake documentation. But - not in Pfeiffer's talk. So I've snipped that part out of the question and left it just with the issue of the separation of files.